# I could not retrive a value from controller page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I have a table named `client`. I need to get the first name from the table and send it to my view page. I have a function in model file to retrieve the client data.
This is my model- function:

```
public function get_cli($id)
    {
    $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('client');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $res = $query->result();
        $row = $res[0];
        return $row->first_name;

    }
```

Here I get my client first name.
This is my controller file. Here I have a function to send the data from the client table to my view page.

```
public function ticket($id)
    {
        $id=$this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['id']=$this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['client']=$this->billing_model->get_cli($id);
        $data['employee']=$this->employee_model->emp_name();
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/ticket_page';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
     }
```

My view page.

```
<label>Client Id:<?=$id?></label>
<input type="text" value="<?=$client['first_name'];?>"/>
```

I am getting a white screen. Why is this happenening? Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: Is your `error_reporting` on? If no then use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and post what error are you getting over here

Comment: add the following items to your index.php file:
`error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors',1)`

Comment: No after changing this I could not get the first_name @sabinadhikari

Comment: are you getting your first name in controller ?

Comment: Place this within your `__construct` function  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: are you getting first name in your model or not ? What do you get when you echo `$row->first_name` in model

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: models/billing_model.php

Line Number: 49

Comment: I am getting this error in my function

Comment: @Anu, please view my answer...

Comment: I viewed it. I am getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your model function to this:

```
public function get_cli($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['first_name']; //returning only the first name key value of first row(0th row) of the result;
}
```

Then On the view page:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$client;?>"/>
```

Which will print only the first name;

#### Another approach:

Change your model function to this:

```
public function get_cli($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; //returning the whole array;
}
```

Then On the view page:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$client[0]['first_name'];?>"/>
```

Which will print only the first name value from the 0th(first row) of the array;

Comment: I tried with this but I am getting a error like this.A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: models/billing_model.php

Line Number: 49


Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\application\models\billing_model.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

You should change your view page to this

`<input type="text" value="<?=$client;?>" />`

This will work as you are returning the firstname in your model not whole array.
So, your `$client` variable will contain the firstname. You dont need to refrence it.
Simply echoing `$client` will work.

Comment: No after changing this I could not get the first_name @sabinadhikari

Answer (score 0):

When you have only single row in result i suggest you to use `row_object()` instead of `result()`

```
public function get_cli($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $res = $query->row_object();
    //$row = $res[0];  no need to write this line
    return $res->first_name;

}
```

for your problem on **your view**
You will get `first_name` in `$client`

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$client?>"/>
```

if you are not getting anything please check your result from database might be null.

Answer (score 0):

USE

$row['first_name'] instead of $row->first_name